# Macro is running in endless loop

Tags: excel, vba

currently, I have a set of codes below which I hope to attain the results as shown in the screenshots below. Somehow, it just runs in endless loop. Any idea how I can make it work?

**Initial input:**

[image]

**To this:**

[image]

```
Sub SplitAllCells()

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim Cla As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim Clb As Range

    Set rng1 = Range("D2:D100")
    Set rng2 = Range("E2:E100")

    For Each Cla In rng1
            If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
                Call SplitCellValueSpecial
            End If
        Next

    For Each Clb In rng2
            If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
                Call SplitCellValueNormal
            End If
        Next


Sub SplitCellValueSpecial():

        Dim str As String
        Dim ArrStr() As String
        Dim i As Long
        Dim y As Long
        Dim RowsAdded As Boolean

        RowsAdded = False
        'Fill variables: str is the value of the active cell, ArrStr splits this value at the comma
        str = ActiveCell.Value
        ArrStr = Split(str, "~ ")

        'Loop through each ArrStr to populate each cell below the activecell

        For i = 0 To UBound(ArrStr)
            ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = ArrStr(i)
            If RowsAdded = False Then
                For y = 1 To UBound(ArrStr)
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlDown
                Next y
                RowsAdded = True
            End If
        Next i


    End Sub

Sub SplitCellValueNormal():



    Dim str As String
    Dim ArrStr() As String

    'Fill variables: str is the value of the active cell, ArrStr splits this value at the comma
    str = ActiveCell.Value
    ArrStr = Split(str, "~ ")

    'Loop through each ArrStr to populate each cell below the activecell

    For i = 0 To UBound(ArrStr)
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = ArrStr(i)
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: You making calls to `ActiveCell`, but you never change it, effectively making calls to the exact same cell all the time..... Note that `Cla` in your first iteration is **not** the same as `ActiveCell`! Avoid using `ActiveCell`, even better than calling worksheetcells are arrays.

Comment: oh wait... you're right i think. any ideas how i could tweak it?

Comment: Specify the target range for your code - e.g. `Dim TargetRange As Range` `Set TargetRange = Sheet1.Range("A1")` - If we put that into the `ActiveCell` context, that is equivilent to clicking `A1` and then running your current code.

Comment: @SamuelEverson ahhh great to see you again! okay, let me try that.

Comment: On a more *to your actual question* topic - stepping through your code - specifically the loop - and observing the Locals window is a good way to see what is going on with the loop.

Comment: ahhhhh, sweet. thanks @SamuelEverson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub main()
    SplitCells Range("D2:D100")
    SplitCells Range("E2:E100")
End Sub

Sub SplitCells(rng As Range)
    Dim i, x, arr, arrV, v, el, c As Range

    arrV = rng.Value   'get the original values
    rng.ClearContents  'remove the content

    'loop over each value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrV, 1)
        v = arrV(i, 1)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            arr = Split(v, "~") 'get an array
            For Each el In arr
                rng(1).Offset(x, 0).Value = el
                x = x + 1
            Next el
        Else
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for the part of splitting the cells. However, I observed that after the codes performed its task, both end output at column D and E is shifted all the way upwards. Is there a way for the results to stay stagnant? So, if **hello~ stackoverflow~ community** is in cell D10, then **hello** and the rest shouldn't be shifted all the way up at the end for both column D and E. Sorry if that sounded confusing.

Comment: What would prevent expanded content from above from overwriting something lower down if it didn't shift?

Comment: hey @tim williams, im sorry if i didn't catch your answer clearly. Please pardon me if I sound off. With your current code, it resembles something like a tetris game, so it will always fill up the above (if there is a blank for both Column D and E). Perhaps, opening another question would be better for this, but i'm going to give it a shot here. Is it possible for the end output to be this; if **hello~ stackoverflow~ community** starts at D10, then **hello** should start at D10 and **community** should end at D12. **row2, row3 and row4** would be push downwards to D13, D14 and D15.

Comment: See my edit  - that might be more like what you want

Comment: Yes! Great! Got it. Thanks so much Tim!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code using arrays (You can place the results at any cell instead of D10)

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, x, e, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long
a = Range("D3").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim b(1 To 10000, 1 To UBound(a, 2))
For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
    k = 0
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        x = Split(a(i, j), "~ ")
        For Each e In x
            k = k + 1
            b(k, j) = e
        Next e
        If k > m Then m = k
    Next i
Next j
Range("D10").Resize(m, UBound(b, 2)).Value = b
End Sub
```

Comment: great! However, i will go ahead with Tim's answer first since I've used his. Thanks so much Yasser!